# Winform designer resets Label size and position properties

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on a project and I need a GUI for it, as I'm making the GUI I add a text/label to my form and when I tried to change the size of it, visual-studio/winform instantly resets it back to its original size, is this a bug?

( this isn't only for size, it also happens to position )

Comment: " I tried to change the size of it" do you observe this behaviour in the designer? how about other properties like tab index?

Comment: @MongZhu other properties work, its just some properties that are like this

Comment: from your description it affects only the designer properties like size and position. What is the value of the `AutoSize` property of the Label?. Have you tried setting the new size values directly in the properties window? does it yield the same result?

Comment: the value of `AutoSize` is `True`, I have tried changing the properties with code but that also doesnt work

Comment: try changing `AutoSize` to `false` in the designer and then change the size by entering new values into the property window in the designer

Comment: works now, tysm!

Comment: I am glad to hear that. you can answer your own question and tell the people how you solved your problem.